# How can I determine the background color of record cell?

Tags: reporting-services

How can I determine the background color of record cell?

Like, I have below scenarios.

```
  ID   Column2  Column3

  1       A       A
  2       B       D
  3       C       C
  4       D       D
  5       E       E
```

Value of column2 and column3 for ID-2 is different, So I highlighted (background color) column3 as updated record. Now I want to highlight ID field(ID-2) as it has updated value in column3. 
 I have few other combination of fields and If they are different interms of value the I want to highlight ID field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this...

```
=SWITCH (
   Fields!Column2.Value <> Fields!Column2.Value, "Yellow",
   Fields!anotherColumn.Value <> Fields!yetAnotherColumn.Value, "Yellow",
   True, Nothing
)
```

This reads...
If Column 2 does not equal column 3 then return "Yellow"
If anotherColumn does not equal yetAnotherColumn then return "Yellow"
else return `Nothing`

`Nothing` is the default value for background and is essentially 'transparent'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you use a SWITCH statement as expression for the background colour

Based on your comment below, if column 3 doesn't equal column 2 then change background colour to Yellow, otherwise Transparent.  Change the Id column of the same row to match

For the Id and Column 3 use the same SWITCH statement as expression for the background colour for each cell respectively.

```
=Switch(
   Fields!Column3.Value <> Fields!Column2.Value, "Yellow",
   true, "Transparent"
)
```

Comment: I have used below expression to set background color of Column3,  =iif(instr(Fields!Column2.Value, Fields!Column3.Value)>0,"Transparent","Yellow")  Now, Based on color of Column3 I want to highlight Column1(ID).

Comment: I know about this solution but I have lot of columns which cause report very slow. Let me tell you slightly different scenario, I have two column(col1 and col2). Col2 has random yellow background color so now how can I highlight col1 wherever col2 has yellow as background color.

Comment: What is the expression that changes the colour of Col2 to yellow?, if you update your question listing out the different combinations then you will get a better answer